# bash script for putting thousands of files, into separate folders

Tags: bash, shell, sh

in a directory, i have thousands of files.

i use the following bash snippet, in order to make these thousands of files, be put in folders, that have each 1000 files,

and i face two issues:

a) now each folder has a prefix of dir_ while i would like it to have a name, that will have 6 digits, if less than 6 in the folder name, leading zeros should be added appropriately.

b) current script, puts first folder, into the last one, for example, i have dir_400325 as the last folder, and in there,i find the bash script i have run, and the dir_1000 folder, which is the first folder created. How could i change this, so the first folder, is not stored into the last one?

#!/bin/bash

```
c=0; d=1000; mkdir -p dir_${d}

for file in *
do
        if [ $c -eq 1000 ]
        then
                d=$(( d + 1000 )); c=0; mkdir -p dir_${d}
        fi
        mv "$file" dir_${d}/
        c=$(( c + 1 ))
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `printf` and a format string to generate your 6-digit directory name with leading zeros (`%06d`), demonstrated in a shell:

```
bash-4.4$ d=1001
bash-4.4$ dir_name=$(printf "/path/to/%06d" $d)
bash-4.4$ echo $dir_name 
/path/to/001001
```

Using an absolute path may help ensure the files end up where you're expecting them and not in some subfolder of your current working directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

c=0
d=1000
dir_name=$(printf "/path/to/%06d" $d)
mkdir -p $dir_name

for file in *
do
    if [ $c -eq 1000 ]
    then
        c=0
        d=$(( d + 1000 ))
        dir_name=$(printf "/path/to/%06d" $d)
        mkdir -p $dir_name
    fi
    if [[ -f "$file" ]]
    then
      mv "$file" $dir_name
      c=$(( c + 1 ))
    fi
done
```

Comment: it works, but i do not understand why i get the following warning, and how i could eliminate it: mv: cannot move '001000' to a subdirectory of itself, '/path/to/001000/001000'

Comment: `001000` is matched by the glob `*`. You could skip non-files (such as directories with `if [[ -f "$file" ]]` as in my edit.